# Why minus 500 a few days ago

Tags: support, downvoting

Many of my posts had -10 and -20 all on one day.

Did I upset someone?

I do not see how all those could get downvotes all in one day.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the specified question.  The core reason for the rep change is identical.